# sencha extjs 4.2 rowexpander architect 3

Tags: extjs, plugins

I'm trying to make a gridpanel with rowexpander. I loaded the rowexpander.js file as javascript at resources. 
this is me code in the override function:

```
Ext.define('login.view.override.gridpanelAllUsers', {
    override: 'login.view.gridpanelAllUsers', 
     plugins: [{
        ptype: 'rowexpander',
        rowBodyTpl : new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl>',
                '<p>this is a test.</p>',
            '</tpl>'

    )

         }]
});
```

anyone knows what i'm doing wrong?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get it working, using the rowexpander.js code found here:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/RowExpander.html#Ext-grid-plugin-RowExpander

The rest of your override code looks fine, assuming you have properly referenced your grid panel.  I have used your code exactly, on a table that I promoted to class, and applied an override to.  Your browser console may narrow down the problem if it persists.

Comment: Yes, using Sencha Architect 3.0.  Are your receiving errors in the console?

Comment: I have upgraded to Architect version 3.1 and row expandera plugin is available in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use -
requires: ['Ext.ux.RowExpander']

in your grid class file.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer would be to upgrade Sench Architect to 3.1